# Spring Boot - database upgrade - run CRUD operation from code level

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, jdbc, liquibase

Currently we are trying to run database upgrade, once application is started successfully, based on `ApplicationReadyEvent`.

```
private void upgradeDatabase() {
    int currentVersion = // initially saved in db_version table - say 1
    if (currentVersion < 2) {
         // the code to upgrade from current version (1) to new version (2)
         // update version number in db_version table
    }
    if (currentVersion < 3) {
         // the code to upgrade from current version (2) to new version (3)
         // update version number in db_version table
    }
}
```

Since there is some business logic behind the data upgrade, these cannot be handled via Liquibase or Flyway or even by SQL.

Is there any better approach provided by Spring Boot to handle database upgrade?

Comment: it depends on what you need. you can also use [customChange](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/custom-change.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's a Liquibase Java API which you may use whenever you need.
Check out this [article](https://www.liquibase.com/blog/3-ways-to-run-liquibase)

The most straightforward way of running Liquibase directly looks like this:

```
java.sql.Connection connection = openConnection(); //your openConnection logic here
Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase("path/to/changelog.xml", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
```